# Lua Nested Table Getting Elements

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a nested table like so:

```
  t1 ={}
  t1[1] = {col1=1,col2=1,col3=1,col4=1}
  t1[2] = {col1=1,col2=1,col3=1,col4=1}
  t1[3] = {col1=1,col2=1,col3=1,col4=1}
  t1[4] = {col1=1,col2=1,col3=1,col4=1}
```

it's actually much larger with 250 items in t1 and 30 items per nested table so what I want to do is loop through and get sub table values like this:

```
 for i = 2, 4 do
  local width = t1[draw.ID].col1 --draw.ID is got elsewhere
 end
```

but changing the number part of `.col1` to the `i` part so when it loops through it gets:

```
 t1[draw.ID].col2
 t1[draw.ID].col3
 t1[draw.ID].col4
```

I'm using Lua 5.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for i= 2, 4 do
  local width = t1[draw.ID]["col" .. i] --draw.ID is got elsewhere
end
```

Answer (score 3):

**Ideally**, `col` would *be* or would *contain* an array-like table or *sequence*. This is a much more scalable way to accomplish what you're trying to do. String concatenation `['col' .. i]` to access table keys in the fashion that you'd access them as an array is costly and unnecessary, **if** it can be avoided. This is *especially* important if this is something you plan to do often and want to work quickly.

```
-- Elements of t1 contain tables with cols.
local t1 = {}
t1[1] = {cols = {1,1,1,1}}
t1[2] = {cols = {1,1,1,1}}
t1[3] = {cols = {1,1,1,1}}
t1[4] = {cols = {1,1,1,1}}

for i=2, 4 do
  local width = t1[draw.ID].cols[i]
end

-- Elements of t1 are the cols.
local t1 = {}
t1[1] = {1,1,1,1}
t1[2] = {1,1,1,1}
t1[3] = {1,1,1,1}
t1[4] = {1,1,1,1}

for i=2, 4 do
  local width = t1[draw.ID][i]
end
```

---

**Edit:** If it's unavoidable that you have to use table keys in the style of `['col' .. i]`, then the best you could do is to cache them for faster access.

```
-- Cache all the possible keys that you'll need.
local colkeys = {}
for i=1, 30 do colkeys[i] = 'col' .. i end

for i=2, 4 do
  local width = t1[draw.ID][colkeys[i]]
end
```

This method is anywhere from **4** to **8** times faster than concatenating a string each time that you need to index the table. It's not the *ideal* solution, but it works if you're stuck with the likes of `col1` to `col30`.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, ended up changing the whole code so the elements of t1 contain tables with cols.